# Rename Exchange email and create new one for Domain User

Tags: active-directory, exchange

I am looking to rename an email thats linked with an existing domain account then create a new email with the same as the original and then link it to the domain account.

The situation is this. We have a user using the 'Maintenance' account and email but we dont want him having access to the previous years worth of email in the mailbox. But we want it to still be accessible by other people or myself.

Its important that the user still have the email 'Maintenance' however.

I could rename the domain account and associated email and then create a new one for him that would be blank but i dont want to have to copy over all the stuff on the users domain account/desktop to the new one if i dont need to.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Export messages from this mailbox to pst, then clean up the mailbox. Optionally import pst content to any other mailbox.

Comment: According to your description, it is exactly what Vadim has said.